# How isotropic is the universe?

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

In Wayne Hu's tutorials, as well as Wikipedia, I've seen the CMB quoted as being isotropic to 1 part in 100,000.  I tried to get a reference for this, so I dug and found out that, after subtracting the dipole, the CMB has a standard deviation of $18 \mu K$.  So I did the calculation myself:
$$\frac{2.7522 K}{18 \mu K}=151,416$$
So doing a little rounding, I get one part in 150,000.  Is there a more recent value for the deviation than [(Wright, 2004)](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0305591)?  What am I missing?  How do all these semi-referenceable but legitimate sources come up with 1 part in 100,000?

Comment: Is that really that much of a difference to be concerned about? I'm guessing that people just use "1 part in 100,000" as a ballpark figure, and 150,000 doesn't seem that far off...

Comment: I dunno.  It seems just about halfway to 2 parts in 100,000.  The main point is, I need a reference and I need to be able to back-up a number I'm trying to publish.  Is the calculation right?

Comment: It’s not uncommon for physicists to round to the nearest power of 10 when   speaking approximately. For example, all I remember about the Planck length is that it’s around $10^{-35}$ m. Who cares if it’s actually 60% higher? Not most people.

Comment: @GluonSoup - one part in 150,000 is about halfway to being 1 part in 200,000, not 2 parts in 100,000. So 1 part in 100,000 slightly undersells it, but is a nice power of 10.

Comment: *Is the calculation right?* Does anyone define a numerical anisotropy in this way? (It seems backward, for one thing.) Assuming the numerator and denominator are correct, you can’t get 6 sig figs out of only 2.

Comment: By “backward” I mean that I would expect a numerical measure of anisotropy to be zero, not infinity, when there is no anisotropy. Why aren’t you dividing the other way?

Comment: *I'm trying to publish* I’m curious... Where are you trying to publish?

Comment: @G.Smith - *Where are you trying to publish*  Probably MNRAS, then Astrophysics Journal.  Why do you ask?

Comment: @G.Smith - *Why aren’t you dividing the other way*  Because numerous sources quote the anisotropy as "1 part in 100,000" (Wiki, Hu, Dodelson, etc.).  I want to quote this figure, but I also want to know **exactly** from where it came.  If I can't reproduce it, I can't quote it.

Comment: *Why do you ask?* I was wondering if you were aiming high or low, and, if high, what the top astrophysics  journals are these days.